# Kodak still camera udev problem

Tags: linux, usb, udev, file-manager

My still camera is not includev in udev list.

lsusb stands:

```
Bus 007 Device 016: ID 040a:058b Kodak Co. Digital Camera
```

So I add to /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/40-libgphoto2.rules

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="040a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="058b", ENV{ID_GPHOTO2}="1", ENV{GPHOTO2_DRIVER}="proprietary"
```

according to the entry for similar unit from the same vendor but different idProduct "058a"

But my camera is not available from any photo app including gwenview or even from any filemanager. Simply can not be mounted as a storage.

Any idea how to correct my entry in udev?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked at Kodak for 15+ years and have used the products extensively. I would recommend getting a card reader and just taking the cards out of the camera and plugging them into the reader instead. You will save yourself a lot of annoyance and aggravations.

USB card readers can usually be picked up for 10-20 US dollars. Ironically I use several that I picked up at the Kodak employee store, they're worth their weight in gold. The readers I purchased could read a variety of card formats and were designed to be portable so they can easily be thrown in the bag with the cameras as well.

I do this for all my cameras, all brands and it's just a lot easier than monkeying around with attaching the cameras to the computer.

#### USB readers

This is the reader that I picked up, it's for sale on Amazon for $7 US dollars.

[image: ss of reader]

There are tons of others that are similar to this one. These readers are often called 40-in-1's or 50-in-1's because they can read a variety of card form-factors.

Comment: Yep. Good advise. But I have to explain it my wife. Too difficult challenge. So as I mentioned before could the camera to be ordinary "USB mass storage device" as under Winows?

Comment: Most of the later Kodak cameras could go in either mode. You had to change it in the firmware/setup of the camera. Which model are you using?

Comment: Of course I have such SD-> USB reader even that one buid in in to the laptop directly. As I mentioned later, the camera setup does not contain "USB mass storage device" or similar option. My camera is Kodak EasyShare Z1012 IS

Comment: @user180586 - I know you mentioned it, I found it odd, given that most of the cameras I have/had from work had the mass storage feature. Odd that this one doesn't. I wanted to search on the model # to see what others had been doing under linux, if any.

Comment: @user180586 - incidentally I found zero info on this camera + Linux.

Comment: @user180586 - I found this method, using `gphotofs`, perhaps it might work for you as well? http://roger.steneteg.org/304/mounting-a-ptp-device/

Comment: Yep. Compiling gphotofs from src.rpm (on my Linux platform) resolved my problem! Now I can see SD card over PTP in any file manager. THX!!!!

Comment: @user180586 - Thats terrific news. Glad that resolved your issue!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Kodak cameras by default present themselves as PTP cameras, not as USB mass storage devices to the USB host. This gives you two possibilities:

- use the camera's menu to switch it to something like "USB mass storage device" instead of something like "PTP camera"
- use the software gphoto2 to obtain pictures from your PTP camera.

If you insist your camera is a USB mass storage device please call

```
hwinfo --block --short
```

This will list all block devices (incl. USB storage devices) visible to your kernel.
I documented my experiences at http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Digital_camera

Comment: Hmm. The problem is that setup does not contains "USB mass storage device". But under Windows, I can see my Kodak camera as exactly "USB mass storage device". So is it possible to do the same in Linux?

Comment: yes. Use a normal kernel, nothing fancy, no modifications to udev. Attach your camera, type hwinfo --block --short. Does a line show up that could be your camera?

Comment: hwinfo --block --short does not show my camera as mass storage device. In menu there is no option "USB mass storage dev". My camera is Kodak EasyShare Z1012 IS.

Comment: I had the EasyShare as well. Try gphoto2 to get all files: gphoto2 --get-all-files

Comment: Compiling gphotofs from src.rpm (on my Linux platform) resolved my problem! Now I can see SD card over PTP in any file manager because SD card inside camera is mounted as filesystem via udev